# Watchdog for specific python process

Tags: python, linux, system, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a python running process in the background

```
python myFunction.py
```

From time to time, `myFunction` process gets killed for unknown reason, however, I want to restart it automatically. I have multiple python process running in the background, and I do not know which one runs `myFunctions.py` (e.g. by using the `pgrep` command).

Is it possible? Can I make a bash or python script to restart the command `python myFunction.py` whenever the python process running it gets killed?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) which is (from its own documentation) :

> a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a
>   number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems

Supervisord will keep your script in check. If it crashes, it will restart it again. If your raspberry reboots it will make sure the scripts starts automically after booting.

It works based on a config file formatted like this (more info in the [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)) :

```
[program:myFunction]
command=/path_to_script/myFunction.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myFunction.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myFunction.error.log
directory=/path_to_script
```

I hope this will help you